# Is there a better way to count certain numbers in a string?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm looking for a way to *count* only *certain numbers*, and decrease by `1` if you cannot find the number when provided with a string.

For example,

```
string test = "987652349";
```

How can I count how many `9`s are in the string? And if no `9`s, count `8` instead? If not, count `7`? Etc.

I have a *complicated* `if` loop that isn't too pleasing to look at. The numbers always start from `9` and looks for that until `1`.

```
for each c in test
    if (test.Contains("9")){
      count = test.Where(x => x == '9').Count();
      blah blah;
    }

    else if (test.Contains("8")){
      count = test.Where(x => x == '8').Count();
      blah blah;
    }
```

etc.

Comment: Are the characters always all digits? `count = test.Count(x => x == test.Max())`?

Comment: Please re-write your "for example" in valid C#.

Comment: While the LINQ solution is best, your loop would be better written as going from `'9'` to `'0'` and breaking out when it is contained in `test`. In fact, as written, your `for each` (sic) loop does nothing useful since you never refer to `c` in your body.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Perhaps two lines? `var maxdigit = test.Max(); var countmaxdigit = test.Count(ch => ch == maxdigit);`

Comment: @NetMage Yes, the linq solution isn't exactly optimal since it runs test.Max() for each character, doing it in two steps is definitely better.

Comment: Yes they are always integer digits!

Answer (score 5):

Single pass solution

```
char charToCount = '0';
int count = 0;

foreach (char c in test) 
  if (c == charToCount)
    count += 1;
  else if (c > charToCount && c <= '9') {
    // if we have a better candidate
    charToCount = c;
    count = 1;
  }

blah blah
```

Comment: Nice thinking! (I would name variable `charToCount` however). Also in `for each`, shouldn't that be `char c` not `int c`? (One reason I like `var`.)

Comment: I couldn't resist a LINQ / one line version: `var countmaxdigit = test.Aggregate((charToCount: '0', count: 0), (maxch_count, ch) => (ch == maxch_count.charToCount) ? (ch, maxch_count.count+1) : (ch > maxch_count.charToCount) ? (ch, 1) : maxch_count).count;` BTW, `++count;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion.

```
    private int Counter(string[] numbers, int countFrom)
    {
            if (countFrom == 0)
                return 0;

            var nrOfMyNr = numbers.Where(x => x == countFrom.ToString()).Count();

            if (nrOfMyNr == 0)
            {
                countFrom -= 1;
                return Counter(numbers, countFrom);
            }

            else
                return nrOfMyNr;
    }
```

and then call it like

```
    var count = Counter(test,9);
```

of course, you need to modify it if you want to now which nr there is x nr of.

Comment: You may want to do something with the return value of Counter in the recursion, maybe return it or assign it to nrOfMyNr?

Comment: sorry, youre right. I have edited

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop:

```
        char c = '9';
        while (c >= '1')
        {
            if (test.Contains(c))
            {
                count = test.Count(x => x == c);
                // blah blah;
                break;
            }

            c--;
        }
```